# Using discrete calculus to study convergence of series and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus

From some personal investigation, I've noticed that all convergence tests for infinite series (at least, the real kind) can be rephrased in terms of the discrete derivative $∆f(x)$ of a function $f(x)$, sometimes to give interesting results.

For example, the statement:
$$\text{If } \lim_{k → ∞} a_k ≠ 0 \text{ then } ∑a_k \text{ diverges.}$$

Is equivalent to the statement:
$$\text{If } \lim_{x → ∞} ∆f(x) ≠ 0 \text{ then } f(x) \text{ diverges.}$$
Except that the second statement is arguably more general, since $f(x)$ is not explicitly required to be in the form of a sum. Note that the limit of $∆ f(x)$ follows the definition of a limit of a sequence, rather than a function.

Another example, is the ratio test which is given:
$$ \text{If } \lim_{k → ∞} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} < 1 \text{ then } ∑a_k \text{ converges.}$$

This statement is equivalent to:
$$ \text{If } \lim_{x → ∞} \frac{∆^{\!2} f(x)}{∆ f(x)} < 0 \text{ then } f(x) \text{ converges.}$$

Besides said generalization, this representation is also interesting because proving convergence tests in terms of $∆ f(x)$ and $f(x)$ does not require manipulating sums directly. Instead, the proofs can be given in terms of basic theorems about $∆ f(x)$. They generally resemble proofs you'd find in calculus.

Is anyone familiar with some thorough treatment of studying infinite series using discrete calculus in this way?

Comment: I don't think you're gaining anything new.  Your function $f$ is only defined on the integers, so is really a sequence: the sequence of partial sums.  This is the standard approach.  Similarly, given any sequence, you get a series by defining $a_n = f(n)-f(n-1)$.

Comment: I didn't say it was some monumental discovery. I just said it was an interesting way to rephrase things.